# Class nested in for loop

Tags: python, oop, pymongo

I have a for loop, inside that for loop is a class. I don't think that's how it is supposed to be laid out. But I'm unsure what terms to search for to solve my problem.

```
for x,y in something:
    do stuff:

    class someclass:
      def__init__(self):
      do stuff
```

The full code can be seen http://pastebin.com/G7fYeqWA

I have tried importing both the modules into each other but that didn't work ended up as a circular dependency

Moving all of the non class code to another file and importing only one module only ran the db inserts on the last team scraped( i understand why)

This is my first attempt at OOP in any language so any advice on that front would be appreciated as well. This program was not OOP to begin with which is why the class is inside the for loop to begin with. All of the aspects oop were added after the initial program( which does work) was written.

From what i can tell i need to be able to call some kind of scrape function from TeamScraper, and put that in to my for loop, only im not sure how to go about it

Comment: If you're refactoring your code into a completely different model, you'll have to learn that model and properly implement it. Don't just translate the code line by line, or you'll end up with weirdness like that.

Comment: Looking at your current code, it's not actually OOP at all. You have a bunch of non-OOP code that happens to run as part of defining the `TeamScraper` class, but you never create any instances of that class, or interact with any of its instance variables. What are you hoping to gain from making this code more object-oriented?

Comment: It basically looks like all the info for a particular team comes from `soup`. I think you should try to write a `TeamScraper` class that takes a single argument in its init method: `__init__(self, soup)`, and populate all the class's instance variables from there. Any further processing should be in a `TeamScraper.do_scrape()` method.

Comment: @Marius I'm trying to learn OOP. I'm having a hard time grasping it outside of small tutorial programs that don't do much. This code doesn't NEED to be OOP but it would be great if i could figure out how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

A class, in any Object Oriented language is a class of objects.  Objects have attributes and methods.  A class simply defines how to create a new object of a particular type.  The main ideas of OO are [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) and [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Putting the definition of a class into a loop is asking the compiler to create that definition over and over and serves absolutely no purpose whatsoever.  The class, itself, tell the program how to create objects of a particular type -- if you are not creating and using the objects, then you have no use for a class definition.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) to get a sense of how python implements OO and [this](http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/02/08/advantages-of-an-object-oriented-approach-for-new-programmers/) to understand *why* OO is used in so many modern, multi-paradigm languages.